# How can I host Laravel web application and other regular sites on the same VPS/Server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laravel, nginx, vps

I have a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) in [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), and I'm currently host [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) web application on it.

It work great and pretty happy with the result so far, and here are my VPS details.

- OS : Ubuntu
- Installed : PHP, MySQL, and NGINX

---

I have a lot of html [`index.html`] and I want to also host my them  in that same VPS/sever. I'm not sure where to start or what is the best way of doing it. I notice that there is a `/var/www/html` directory in my VPS, should I throw my `index.html` in there ?

I tried throw about index.html in there, and when I tried go to them in URL, I got 404 error from my laravel application.

No idea now...

---

**Laravel Web Application URL**

- www.my-site.com/

**Other sites URL**

- www.my-site.com/site1
- www.my-site.com/site2
- www.my-site.com/site3

---

How do I do that ? I've been researching about this for a couple days now, I didn't get any good results so far.

Any direction on that will be much appreciated !